# Remind a user about their account if they have not used it for 6 months

Tags: cron, user-registration

I have a website working with a user registration/login system all working also.

I wish to automatically send all users an email that have not used their account for 6 months. I have an idea, but just wondered if there would be a better/more convenient solution.

Because this will be done in PHP, I guess this requires a cron job, which isnt a problem as I have done many of them before. Wordpress just doesnt seem to store the last time a user visits my site (to my knowledge). I then thought I could just store in the database (manually) the last time a user visits the site, and run a comparison to the current date in a PHP cron file.

Has anyone got a better suggestion? Or even a plugin to do it for me :p

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Transients API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API). It's meant to store data temporary. Note, that this doesn't replace a cron job, as it needs "Action" on the site. So if the site isn't requested, where you set/alter/delete a Transient, then nothing happens.